# Laravel inline if statement in select

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I would like to know if it is possible to add an inline if statement in Laravel's form select element

I am able to do it this way:

```
<select>
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
{!! $variable=='Hello'?'<option value="3">Three</option>':'' !!}
</select>
```

But I would like to know if there is a way similar to this:

```
{!! Form::select('action',array('1'=>'One','2'=>'Two',@if($variable=='Hello') '3'=>'three' @endif),null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```

Comment: it is possible, but why getting the forms in the blade ? get it in your controller and send it to your blade afterward.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to first populate the array and use the if statement and then pass the array to the Form:select

```
<?php
$selectOptions = array();
$selectOptions[1] = 'one';
$selectOptions[2] = 'two';
if($variable == "Hello") {
    $selectOptions[3] = 'three';
}

?>

{!! Form::select('action',$selectOptions,null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```

Comment: I've done this way already but I was curious if it was able to do it all in a single line

Answer (score 0):

there's a clean way to do with ,
register a function in your helper php file 
example it will be called options

```
function  options($variable)
{
$options = [];
$options[1] = "One";
$options[2] = "Two";
$options[3] = $variable=='Hello'?3:4;
return $options
};
```

and in your form set your select with this way

```
{!! Form::select('action',options($variable),null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```